# How can I get the number from iterator object. (Python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

A method returns iterator object.
I want to check the number of data to test.

I think it is a simple question, but I coundn't resolve it.

```
    records = a_function()
    self.assertEqual(1, len(records)) # TypeError: object of type 'listiterator' has no len()
```

Python2.7

Comment: There is no question in your post. What do you mean with _number of data_?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert the iterator to a list first:

```
len(list(records))
```

See:

```
>>> some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> it = iter(list)
>>> it = iter(some_list)
>>> len(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'list_iterator' has no len()
>>> len(list(it))
5
>>>
```

Note, however, that this will consume the iterator:

```
>>> list(it)
[]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine.
Yes, `records` is iterator object, this name is not suitable, I think. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it by

```
sum(1 for _ in it)
```

where `it` is the iterator you want to find length.

Comment: That's a bit cheeky: dupe flagging and then posting an answer. But I'll let you get away with it this time. ;)

Comment: ;). Wont repeat again